# MVVM Floating Pane in Avalon Dock 2 (via Caliburn)

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, avalondock

**How can I bind to a model such that Avalon Dock 2 treats it as a floating pane?**

In basic terms I want to open a window that can be docked and ideally have a MVVM solution. But the furthest I've been able to get to is to get anchorables and no way I can see to entice the docking manager to make them floating.

```
<xcad:DockingManager AnchorablesSource="{Binding Tools}">

    <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>    
        </Style>
    </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

    <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding . }" IsTabStop="False" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>

</xcad:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done what you're suggesting with the floating windows, but I have managed to integrate Caliburn.Micro with AvalonDock.  You'll need a couple of examples to help you and documentation.

1. Download [AvalonDock Source Code](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)
2. Download [Gemini Source Code](https://github.com/tgjones/gemini) (Mash up of Caliburn.Micro and AvalonDock).

In short, use the LayoutInitializer in conjuction with  a property on your ToolViewModelBase to indicate that the anchorable should be opened as floating.

```xml
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
  <local:LayoutInitializer/>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
```

The AvalonDock source code of interest is below and you'll find equivalents in Gemini.

.\Version2.0\AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp\ToolViewModel.cs

.\Version2.0\AvalonDock.MVVMTestApp\LayoutInitializer.cs

Comment: [Avalon Documentation by Xceed](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.html).

Comment: Cheers I'll investigate this approach. Layout strategy wasn't known to me and seems rather useful especially if your ViewModels implement ILayoutUpdateStrategy